# i am unable to solve this error. i am completely new for python. please explain my error and solution for this

Tags: python

I can not assign float to `marks`. What is the best way to handle this program?

```
print("enter marks of student obtained in five diff subjects")
float marks = []
for i in range(0,4):
    n=input()
    marks.append(n)
    agg = sum(marks)

print("perentage of student is %0.2f " (agg))
```

Error screen look like this:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\windows 7\c.py", line 2
    float marks = []
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Use `marks = []` i.e., don't specify data type.

Comment: Python doesn't have strict typing

Comment: Also the last print statement is incorrect, you need to add a percent sign: `print("perentage of student is %0.2f " % (agg))`

Comment: Please don't post questions with titles like this. A title should be *short* summary of the problem or describe the overall topic, not your entire question.

Comment: I have updated the answer to make `agg` working

Answer (score 1):

Inside the for loop

```
n=input()
marks.append(n)
```

Is actually appending strings into `marks` list.
So you should change the code inside the loop to add float numbers into `marks` or just remove `float` from `float marks = []` to make `marks` be able to contain strings.
To make this piece of code working you will also need to cast the marks to `int` or `float` in order to calculate the `agg` as following:

```py
print("enter marks of student obtained in five diff subjects")
agg = 0
for i in range(4):
    agg = agg + int(input())

print("perentage of student is %0.2f " % (agg))
```

or alternatively you can do this:

```py
print("enter marks of student obtained in five diff subjects")
marks = []
for i in range(4):
    n=input()
    marks.append(n)

agg = sum(map(int, marks))
print("perentage of student is %0.2f " % (agg))
```

Comment: `int(marks)` isn't correct. Think you want `sum(map(int, marks))`. Also, unindent that line

Comment: You are right @OneCricketeer. But we should add single mark each iteration or sum all the marks finally, not each iteration.

Comment: `agg + int(marks)` is still incorrect. Did you mean `int(n)`? If so, why not start with `int(input())`?

Comment: Sorry, but You are right again :) Going to change the answer again. Thanks!